# Making section headings bold and sans serif

Tags: fonts, sectioning, bold, sans-serif

I would like to make section headings bold and sans-serif (`helvet` package). I found a snippet that produces sans serif headings:

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
  {1em}{1em}{\normalsize\sf}}
```

Now I have the problem that `\sf\bf` does not produce bold and sans-serif text. I know that nesting of `\textbf` etc. macros does the trick but I wonder how I should incorporate this into my snippet.

Comment: don't use `\sf`  or `\bf` they don't combine as you saw (and the command is not even defined by default in LaTeX), use `\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries` but note not every sans font has a bold variant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command `\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}` of the `sectsty` package achieves this easily.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.